# Rails postgresql: Error with camel case columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run this very simple query

```
unless ram.blank?
      list = list.where(['numRam >= ?', ram])
end
```

it works perfectly on my local server where I am using mysql as my database, but it gives me this error in production where I use psql

```
2017-05-07 11:13:57 UTC ERROR:  column "numram" does not exist at character 68
2017-05-07 11:13:57 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mobiles" WHERE "mobiles"."visible" = $1 AND (numRam >= '5')
```

Apparently, it changed `numRam` to `numram` which doesn't exist in my database. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this trick:

```
unless ram.blank?
  list = list.where(['"numRam" >=?', ram])
end
```

Comment: Here is the new error
2017-05-07 11:51:25 UTC ERROR:  column "numRam >= '1'" does not exist at character 68
2017-05-07 11:51:25 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mobiles" WHERE "mobiles"."visible" = $1 AND ("numRam >= '1'")

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'"numRam" >=?'`

Comment: yes `'"numRam" >=?'` solved the issue on psql. However, it isn't functioning anymore on mysql which is fine. My advice is not to use camelcase in psql and try to use the same db in development and production.

Comment: Definitely use the same db in dev and prod, anything else is a constant source of frustration. Can't you change your column name however in production to get around this hack?